# Autocomplete Search List issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

Im currently developing an webapplication that are going to have an Autocomplete search form, the results are being updated from an Sql Database. The whole "functionality" is working except of one thing. The client is calling an C# Webservice which are going to return an array to the client. The thing is. The list of the client shows the same results multiply times. So if theres only one match from the database the client shows that match like 20-25 times in an vertical list. I don't know how to solve this, please help.

**C# Webservice:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication6
{

public class searchResult
{
    public string Title;
    public string img;
    public string href;
}

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptType(typeof(searchResult))]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public searchResult[] Search(string txtSearch)
    {
        //Semuler to slow internet connection
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        //Declare collection of searchResult
        List<searchResult> resultList = new List<searchResult>();

        string constr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; ;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DriverInfo], [Teams], [Tracks] WHERE UserName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%' OR TeamName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%' OR TrackName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%'";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                searchResult DriverResult = new searchResult();
                DriverResult.Title = dr["UserName"].ToString();
                DriverResult.img = "driver.png";
                DriverResult.href = dr["UserId"].ToString();

                if (DriverResult.Title.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.ToLower()))
                {
                    resultList.Add(DriverResult);
                }

                searchResult TeamResult = new searchResult();
                TeamResult.Title = dr["TeamName"].ToString();
                TeamResult.img = "team.png";
                TeamResult.href = dr["Id"].ToString();

                if (TeamResult.Title.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.ToLower()))
                {
                    resultList.Add(TeamResult);
                }

                searchResult TrackResult = new searchResult();
                TrackResult.Title = dr["TrackName"].ToString();
                TrackResult.img = "track.png";
                TrackResult.href = dr["TrackId"].ToString();

                if (TrackResult.Title.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.ToLower()))
                {
                    resultList.Add(TrackResult);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return resultList.ToArray();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        function search() {
        if ($("#txtSearch").val() != "") {

        $(".divResult").show(); //show div block that contains on result
        $(".loading").show(); // show loading text while getting result

    //call web searvice
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "WebService.asmx/Search", //function that in web service
                data: "{txtSearch:'" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "'}",// passing value of txtSearch input
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
        //declaer client object and set to it returned result from web sevice function
                    var result = response.d;
                    $(".record").html(""); // clear previous result

        //looping in 'result' array to get data and fill it inside ".record" div as html
                    $.each(result, function(index, res) {

            //append img tag inside ".record" div
                        $('<img />', {
                            src: 'Images/' + res.img,
                            alt: res.Title
                        }).addClass("img").appendTo('.record');

            //append anchor tag inside ".record" div
                        $('<a></a>', {
                            href: res.href,
                            text: res.Title
                        }).addClass("txtResult").appendTo('.record');

                        $(".record").append("<hr />");
                    });
        //hide loading div when the data was got
                    $(".loading").hide();
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    $(".record").html(msg.d);
                }

            });

        }
        else {
        $(".divResult").hide(); //hide div that contains result when the input text is empty
        $(".record").html(""); //also loading text when the input text is empty
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <input id="txtSearch" onkeyup="search()" type="text" />
<div class="divResult">
<div class="loading">Loading..</div>
<div class="record"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
        .content
    {
        margin:50px auto;
        text-align:center;
        width:322px;
    }

    #txtSearch
    {
        border:solid 1px #cccccc;
        width:320px;
        color:#555555;
        font: 18pt tahoma;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .divResult
    {
        position:absolute;
        background-color:#F2F2FF;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#999999;
        width:320px;
        text-align:left;
        display:none;
    }
    .img
    {
        padding-top: 2px;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
    }
    .txtResult
    {
        display:block;
        width:320px;
        height:30px;
        color:#3c5899;
        font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .txtResult:hover {
        background-color: #3c5899;
        color: White;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font: 10pt tahoma;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .record
    {
        margin:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of join you're doing in your SQL query is not recommended, and it may account for your duplicate results.  I'd suggest something more like this:

```
select 'Driver' as Type, UserId as Id, UserName as Name 
from DriverInfo 
where UserName like '%foo%'

union 

select 'Team' as Type, Id, TeamName 
from Teams
where TeamName like '%foo%'

union 

select 'Track' as Type, TrackId, TrackName 
from Tracks
where TrackName like '%foo%'
```

This would give you results like this:

```
Type      Id       Name
----      --       ----
Driver    23       Foo
Driver    73       Foo Jr.
Team      27       Team Foo
Team      64       Team Foobar
Track     98       Bar Foo Field
```

Here's how you could consume these results:

```
while (dr.Read())
{

    resultList.Add(
        new searchResult {
            Title = dr["Name"].ToString(),
            img = dr["Type"].ToString() + ".png",
            href = dr["UserId"].ToString() } );
}
```

As is, you're probably getting results like these (a cartesian product), where the number of results wont be `A + B + C`, but rather `A * B * C`:

```
UserId  UserName      Id  TeamName       TrackId  TrackName      ...
------  --------      --  --------       -------  ---------      ---
23      Foo           27  Team Foo       98       Bar Foo Field  ...
23      Foo           64  Team Foobar    98       Bar Foo Field  ...
73      Foo Jr.       27  Team Foo       98       Bar Foo Field  ...
73      Foo Jr.       64  Team Foobar    98       Bar Foo Field  ...
```

Also, notice that since `select *` is being used, you'll get more columns than you need.

**Update**:

You said you weren't sure with how to add your variables to the query.  You should use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation to make your code cleaner and to protect against SQL injection attacks:

```
cmd.CommandText = "... where UserName like @SearchPattern ... where TeamName like @SearchPattern ...";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchPattern", txtSearch + "%");
```

Comment: Exactly as phoog's answer. It keeps searching forever without any matches

Comment: Are you sure the search just isn't slow or that you're not getting an error while running the query?  Do you have a lot of rows?  Doing a `like '%...%'` is typically a very expensive operation without the proper indexing.  Try running the query directly on the database (i.e. with SQL Management Studio if you're using MSSQL).

Comment: Worked correctly in management studio. Could we please open a chat conversation to fix this?

Comment: Ha, I actually can't figure out how to make this into a chat.  If the query runs in Management Studio, then you must be getting a runtime error in your code.  If you post which error you're getting, we can help you further.

Comment: The problem seems to be i don't know how to convert that query to work as a string in c#. I mean with all the "" and stuff. Could you help me with that?

Comment: See my update.  Use parameters in your query.  You'll also have to either convert my sample query to a single line so it fits in a standard C# string, or surround the string with `@""` so it can span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's the cartesian product query: `SELECT * FROM [DriverInfo], [Teams], [Tracks] WHERE UserName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%' OR TeamName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%' OR TrackName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%'"`

(Search the web for `cartesian product join` for more information.)

I suppose you either want to join the tables or make a union of them.  From your example, I expect it would be a union.  This has the advantage of letting the db server do more of the work, and it reduces network traffic.

Example:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT UserName FROM [DriverInfo]"
    + "WHERE UserName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%'"
    + "UNION SELECT TeamName FROM [Teams]"
    + "WHERE TeamName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%'"
    + "UNION SELECT TrackName FROM [Tracks]"
    + "WHERE TrackName LIKE '" + txtSearch + "%'"
```

But you really must use a parameter rather than concatenating the txtSearch value inline.  Otherwise you are seriously vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.  (Search the web for `SQL injection attack` for more information.)